# Unable to shutdown Raspberry connected to UPS

Tags: power, power-supply, connection, ups

I'm quite new to Raspberry world and I need you help :)

I've configured my Pi as a small NAS and download station but I also use it to manage some sensors in my house, so I bought an UPS.

The UPS is an APC Back-Ups Pro 900 and I correctly configured apcupsd on the Raspberry to monitor power failure events, in fact I get emails on onbattery and offbattery events. Raspberry is directly connected to the UPS using the supplied Ethernet-to-USB cable.

Unfortunately, I can't manage to shutdown the Raspberry when UPS battery is low. I tried to write a doshutdown script, which gets called, but the Raspberry won't shutdown.
I searched a lot on the Internet and everybody says it is quite simple but I really don't understand why my configuration doesn't work...
Can you help me?
Thank you so much!

*apcupsd.conf file*

```
## apcupsd.conf v1.1 ##
# 
#  for apcupsd release 3.14.12 (29 March 2014) - debian
#
# "apcupsd" POSIX config file

#
# ========= General configuration parameters ============
#

# UPSNAME xxx
#   Use this to give your UPS a name in log files and such. This
#   is particulary useful if you have multiple UPSes. This does not
#   set the EEPROM. It should be 8 characters or less.
UPSNAME ApcUpsMC

# UPSCABLE <cable>
#   Defines the type of cable connecting the UPS to your computer.
#
#   Possible generic choices for <cable> are:
#     simple, smart, ether, usb
#
#   Or a specific cable model number may be used:
#     940-0119A, 940-0127A, 940-0128A, 940-0020B,
#     940-0020C, 940-0023A, 940-0024B, 940-0024C,
#     940-1524C, 940-0024G, 940-0095A, 940-0095B,
#     940-0095C, 940-0625A, M-04-02-2000
#
UPSCABLE usb

# To get apcupsd to work, in addition to defining the cable
# above, you must also define a UPSTYPE, which corresponds to
# the type of UPS you have (see the Description for more details).
# You must also specify a DEVICE, sometimes referred to as a port.
# For USB UPSes, please leave the DEVICE directive blank. For
# other UPS types, you must specify an appropriate port or address.
#
# UPSTYPE   DEVICE           Description
# apcsmart  /dev/tty**       Newer serial character device, appropriate for 
#                            SmartUPS models using a serial cable (not USB).
#
# usb       <BLANK>          Most new UPSes are USB. A blank DEVICE
#                            setting enables autodetection, which is
#                            the best choice for most installations.
#
# net       hostname:port    Network link to a master apcupsd through apcupsd's 
#                            Network Information Server. This is used if the
#                            UPS powering your computer is connected to a 
#                            different computer for monitoring.
#
# snmp      hostname:port:vendor:community
#                            SNMP network link to an SNMP-enabled UPS device.
#                            Hostname is the ip address or hostname of the UPS 
#                            on the network. Vendor can be can be "APC" or 
#                            "APC_NOTRAP". "APC_NOTRAP" will disable SNMP trap 
#                            catching; you usually want "APC". Port is usually 
#                            161. Community is usually "private".
#
# netsnmp   hostname:port:vendor:community
#                            OBSOLETE
#                            Same as SNMP above but requires use of the 
#                            net-snmp library. Unless you have a specific need
#                            for this old driver, you should use 'snmp' instead.
#
# dumb      /dev/tty**       Old serial character device for use with 
#                            simple-signaling UPSes.
#
# pcnet     ipaddr:username:passphrase:port
#                            PowerChute Network Shutdown protocol which can be 
#                            used as an alternative to SNMP with the AP9617 
#                            family of smart slot cards. ipaddr is the IP 
#                            address of the UPS management card. username and 
#                            passphrase are the credentials for which the card 
#                            has been configured. port is the port number on 
#                            which to listen for messages from the UPS, normally 
#                            3052. If this parameter is empty or missing, the 
#                            default of 3052 will be used.
#
# modbus    /dev/tty**       Serial device for use with newest SmartUPS models
#                            supporting the MODBUS protocol.
#
UPSTYPE usb
DEVICE

# POLLTIME <int>
#   Interval (in seconds) at which apcupsd polls the UPS for status. This
#   setting applies both to directly-attached UPSes (UPSTYPE apcsmart, usb, 
#   dumb) and networked UPSes (UPSTYPE net, snmp). Lowering this setting
#   will improve apcupsd's responsiveness to certain events at the cost of
#   higher CPU utilization. The default of 60 is appropriate for most
#   situations.
#POLLTIME 60

# LOCKFILE <path to lockfile>
#   Path for device lock file. Not used on Win32.
LOCKFILE /var/lock

# SCRIPTDIR <path to script directory>
#   Directory in which apccontrol and event scripts are located.
SCRIPTDIR /etc/apcupsd

# PWRFAILDIR <path to powerfail directory>
#   Directory in which to write the powerfail flag file. This file
#   is created when apcupsd initiates a system shutdown and is
#   checked in the OS halt scripts to determine if a killpower
#   (turning off UPS output power) is required.
PWRFAILDIR /etc/apcupsd

# NOLOGINDIR <path to nologin directory>
#   Directory in which to write the nologin file. The existence
#   of this flag file tells the OS to disallow new logins.
NOLOGINDIR /etc


#
# ======== Configuration parameters used during power failures ==========
#

# The ONBATTERYDELAY is the time in seconds from when a power failure
#   is detected until we react to it with an onbattery event.
#
#   This means that, apccontrol will be called with the powerout argument
#   immediately when a power failure is detected.  However, the
#   onbattery argument is passed to apccontrol only after the 
#   ONBATTERYDELAY time.  If you don't want to be annoyed by short
#   powerfailures, make sure that apccontrol powerout does nothing
#   i.e. comment out the wall.
ONBATTERYDELAY 3

# 
# Note: BATTERYLEVEL, MINUTES, and TIMEOUT work in conjunction, so
# the first that occurs will cause the initation of a shutdown.
#

# If during a power failure, the remaining battery percentage
# (as reported by the UPS) is below or equal to BATTERYLEVEL, 
# apcupsd will initiate a system shutdown.
BATTERYLEVEL 5

# If during a power failure, the remaining runtime in minutes 
# (as calculated internally by the UPS) is below or equal to MINUTES,
# apcupsd, will initiate a system shutdown.
MINUTES 3

# If during a power failure, the UPS has run on batteries for TIMEOUT
# many seconds or longer, apcupsd will initiate a system shutdown.
# A value of 0 disables this timer.
#
#  Note, if you have a Smart UPS, you will most likely want to disable
#    this timer by setting it to zero. That way, you UPS will continue
#    on batteries until either the % charge remaing drops to or below BATTERYLEVEL,
#    or the remaining battery runtime drops to or below MINUTES.  Of course,
#    if you are testing, setting this to 60 causes a quick system shutdown
#    if you pull the power plug.   
#  If you have an older dumb UPS, you will want to set this to less than
#    the time you know you can run on batteries.
TIMEOUT 10

#  Time in seconds between annoying users to signoff prior to
#  system shutdown. 0 disables.
ANNOY 300

# Initial delay after power failure before warning users to get
# off the system.
ANNOYDELAY 60

# The condition which determines when users are prevented from
# logging in during a power failure.
# NOLOGON <string> [ disable | timeout | percent | minutes | always ]
NOLOGON disable

# If KILLDELAY is non-zero, apcupsd will continue running after a
# shutdown has been requested, and after the specified time in
# seconds attempt to kill the power. This is for use on systems
# where apcupsd cannot regain control after a shutdown.
# KILLDELAY <seconds>  0 disables
KILLDELAY 0

#
# ==== Configuration statements for Network Information Server ====
#

# NETSERVER [ on | off ] on enables, off disables the network
#  information server. If netstatus is on, a network information
#  server process will be started for serving the STATUS and
#  EVENT data over the network (used by CGI programs).
NETSERVER on

# NISIP <dotted notation ip address>
#  IP address on which NIS server will listen for incoming connections.
#  This is useful if your server is multi-homed (has more than one
#  network interface and IP address). Default value is 0.0.0.0 which
#  means any incoming request will be serviced. Alternatively, you can
#  configure this setting to any specific IP address of your server and 
#  NIS will listen for connections only on that interface. Use the
#  loopback address (127.0.0.1) to accept connections only from the
#  local machine.
NISIP 127.0.0.1

# NISPORT <port> default is 3551 as registered with the IANA
#  port to use for sending STATUS and EVENTS data over the network.
#  It is not used unless NETSERVER is on. If you change this port,
#  you will need to change the corresponding value in the cgi directory
#  and rebuild the cgi programs.
NISPORT 3551

# If you want the last few EVENTS to be available over the network
# by the network information server, you must define an EVENTSFILE.
EVENTSFILE /var/log/apcupsd.events

# EVENTSFILEMAX <kilobytes>
#  By default, the size of the EVENTSFILE will be not be allowed to exceed
#  10 kilobytes.  When the file grows beyond this limit, older EVENTS will
#  be removed from the beginning of the file (first in first out).  The
#  parameter EVENTSFILEMAX can be set to a different kilobyte value, or set
#  to zero to allow the EVENTSFILE to grow without limit.
EVENTSFILEMAX 10

#
# ========== Configuration statements used if sharing =============
#            a UPS with more than one machine

#
# Remaining items are for ShareUPS (APC expansion card) ONLY
#

# UPSCLASS [ standalone | shareslave | sharemaster ]
#   Normally standalone unless you share an UPS using an APC ShareUPS
#   card.
UPSCLASS standalone

# UPSMODE [ disable | share ]
#   Normally disable unless you share an UPS using an APC ShareUPS card.
UPSMODE disable

#
# ===== Configuration statements to control apcupsd system logging ========
#

# Time interval in seconds between writing the STATUS file; 0 disables
STATTIME 0

# Location of STATUS file (written to only if STATTIME is non-zero)
STATFILE /var/log/apcupsd.status

# LOGSTATS [ on | off ] on enables, off disables
# Note! This generates a lot of output, so if         
#       you turn this on, be sure that the
#       file defined in syslog.conf for LOG_NOTICE is a named pipe.
#  You probably do not want this on.
LOGSTATS off

# Time interval in seconds between writing the DATA records to
#   the log file. 0 disables.
DATATIME 0

# FACILITY defines the logging facility (class) for logging to syslog. 
#          If not specified, it defaults to "daemon". This is useful 
#          if you want to separate the data logged by apcupsd from other
#          programs.
#FACILITY DAEMON

#
# ========== Configuration statements used in updating the UPS EPROM =========
#

#
# These statements are used only by apctest when choosing "Set EEPROM with conf
# file values" from the EEPROM menu. THESE STATEMENTS HAVE NO EFFECT ON APCUPSD.
#

# UPS name, max 8 characters 
#UPSNAME UPS_IDEN

# Battery date - 8 characters
#BATTDATE mm/dd/yy

# Sensitivity to line voltage quality (H cause faster transfer to batteries)  
# SENSITIVITY H M L        (default = H)
#SENSITIVITY H

# UPS delay after power return (seconds)
# WAKEUP 000 060 180 300   (default = 0)
#WAKEUP 60

# UPS Grace period after request to power off (seconds)
# SLEEP 020 180 300 600    (default = 20)
#SLEEP 180

# Low line voltage causing transfer to batteries
# The permitted values depend on your model as defined by last letter 
#  of FIRMWARE or APCMODEL. Some representative values are:
#    D 106 103 100 097
#    M 177 172 168 182
#    A 092 090 088 086
#    I 208 204 200 196     (default = 0 => not valid)
#LOTRANSFER  208

# High line voltage causing transfer to batteries
# The permitted values depend on your model as defined by last letter 
#  of FIRMWARE or APCMODEL. Some representative values are:
#    D 127 130 133 136
#    M 229 234 239 224
#    A 108 110 112 114
#    I 253 257 261 265     (default = 0 => not valid)
#HITRANSFER 253

# Battery charge needed to restore power
# RETURNCHARGE 00 15 50 90 (default = 15)
#RETURNCHARGE 15

# Alarm delay 
# 0 = zero delay after pwr fail, T = power fail + 30 sec, L = low battery, N = never
# BEEPSTATE 0 T L N        (default = 0)
#BEEPSTATE T

# Low battery warning delay in minutes
# LOWBATT 02 05 07 10      (default = 02)
#LOWBATT 2

# UPS Output voltage when running on batteries
# The permitted values depend on your model as defined by last letter 
#  of FIRMWARE or APCMODEL. Some representative values are:
#    D 115
#    M 208
#    A 100
#    I 230 240 220 225     (default = 0 => not valid)
#OUTPUTVOLTS 230

# Self test interval in hours 336=2 weeks, 168=1 week, ON=at power on
# SELFTEST 336 168 ON OFF  (default = 336)
#SELFTEST 336
```

*apccontrol file*

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (C) 1999-2002 Riccardo Facchetti <riccardo@master.oasi.gpa.it>
#
#  for apcupsd release 3.14.12 (29 March 2014) - debian
#
# platforms/apccontrol.  Generated from apccontrol.in by configure.
#
#  Note, this is a generic file that can be used by most
#   systems. If a particular system needs to have something
#   special, start with this file, and put a copy in the
#   platform subdirectory.
#

#
# These variables are needed for set up the autoconf other variables.
#
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}

APCPID=/var/run/apcupsd.pid
APCUPSD=/sbin/apcupsd
SHUTDOWN=/sbin/shutdown
SCRIPTSHELL=/bin/sh
SCRIPTDIR=/etc/apcupsd
WALL=wall

export SYSADMIN=root
export APCUPSD_MAIL="mail"
if [ -f $SCRIPTDIR/config ]; then . $SCRIPTDIR/config ; fi

#
# Concatenate all output from this script to the events file
#  Note, the following kills the script in a power fail situation
#   where the disks are mounted read-only.
# exec >>/var/log/apcupsd.events 2>&1

#
# This piece is to substitute the default behaviour with your own script,
# perl, or C program.
# You can customize every single command creating an executable file (may be a
# script or a compiled program) and calling it the same as the $1 parameter
# passed by apcupsd to this script.
#
# After executing your script, apccontrol continues with the default action.
# If you do not want apccontrol to continue, exit your script with exit 
# code 99. E.g. "exit 99".
#
# WARNING: the apccontrol file will be overwritten every time you update your
# apcupsd, doing `make install'. Your own customized scripts will _not_ be
# overwritten. If you wish to make changes to this file (discouraged), you
# should change apccontrol.sh.in and then rerun the configure process.
#
if [ -f ${SCRIPTDIR}/${1} -a -x ${SCRIPTDIR}/${1} ]
then
    ${SCRIPTDIR}/${1} ${2} ${3} ${4}
    # exit code 99 means he does not want us to do default action
    if [ $? = 99 ] ; then
    exit 0
    fi
fi

case "$1" in
    killpower)
    echo "Apccontrol doing: ${APCUPSD} --killpower on UPS ${2}" | #${WALL}
    sleep 10
    ${APCUPSD} --killpower
    echo "Apccontrol has done: ${APCUPSD} --killpower on UPS ${2}" | #${WALL}
    ;;
    commfailure)
    echo "Warning communications lost with UPS ${2}" | #${WALL}
    ;;
    commok)
    echo "Communications restored with UPS ${2}" | #${WALL}
    ;;
#
# powerout, onbattery, offbattery, mainsback events occur
#   in that order.
#
    powerout)
    ;;
    onbattery)
    echo "Power failure on UPS ${2}. Running on batteries." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    offbattery)
    echo "Power has returned on UPS ${2}..." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    mainsback)
    if [ -f /etc/apcupsd/powerfail ] ; then
       printf "Continuing with shutdown."  | #${WALL}
    fi
    ;;
    failing)
    echo "Battery power exhausted on UPS ${2}. Doing shutdown." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    timeout)
    echo "Battery time limit exceeded on UPS ${2}. Doing shutdown." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    loadlimit)
    echo "Remaining battery charge below limit on UPS ${2}. Doing shutdown." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    runlimit)
    echo "Remaining battery runtime below limit on UPS ${2}. Doing shutdown." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    doreboot)
    echo "UPS ${2} initiating Reboot Sequence" | #${WALL}
    ${SHUTDOWN} -r now "apcupsd UPS ${2} initiated reboot"
    ;;
    doshutdown)
    sudo /sbin/shutdown now
    echo "UPS ${2} initiated Shutdown Sequence"
    ;;
    annoyme)
    echo "Power problems with UPS ${2}. Please logoff." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    emergency)
    echo "Emergency Shutdown. Possible battery failure on UPS ${2}." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    changeme)
    echo "Emergency! Batteries have failed on UPS ${2}. Change them NOW" | #${WALL}
    ;;
    remotedown)
    echo "Remote Shutdown. Beginning Shutdown Sequence." | #${WALL}
    ;;
    startselftest)
    ;;
    endselftest)
    ;;
    battdetach)
    ;;
    battattach)
    ;;
    *)  echo "Usage: ${0##*/} command"
    echo "       warning: this script is intended to be launched by"
    echo "       apcupsd and should never be launched by users."
    exit 1
    ;;
esca
```

*apcupsd.events log file*

```
2016-01-02 19:17:03 +0100  apcupsd 3.14.12 (29 March 2014) debian startup succeeded
2016-01-02 19:17:05 +0100  Power failure.
2016-01-02 19:17:08 +0100  Running on UPS batteries.
2016-01-02 19:17:19 +0100  Reached run time limit on batteries.
2016-01-02 19:17:19 +0100  Initiating system shutdown!
2016-01-02 19:17:19 +0100  User logins prohibited
2016-01-02 19:46:12 +0100  Mains returned. No longer on UPS batteries.
2016-01-02 19:46:12 +0100  Power is back. UPS running on mains.
2016-01-02 19:46:12 +0100  Allowing logins
```

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538  You should also glance through `/var/log/syslog` for that time period.

Answer (score 0):

Shutting down your Pi via script should be simple, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20851174/raspberrypi-shutdown-script or [Shutdown the Pi at the end of my python script using cron?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61202/shutdown-the-pi-at-the-end-of-my-python-script-using-cron)

I have seen questions and answers here with similar issues to yours (a script not really sutting Pi down), but generally with the code in the links I posted you may succeed.